# how to fix repo upload failed with urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known?

Tags: git, repo

I have created my own git server with repo.
The git works fine.
And the repo could sync the code to the server.
But when i used "repo upload ." it failed.
The log is

```
:~/retest/build/ap$ repo upload .

Upload project ap/ to remote branch master:

branch mifi ( 1 commit, Thu Jul 27 21:20:21 2017 +0800):

     3da5c7d8 build:first build

to null (y/N)? y

----------------------------------------------------------------------

FAILED ap/             mifi

   (null: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>)
```

The .git/config is

```
:~/retest/build/ap$ cat .git/config

core

    repositoryformatversion = 0

    filemode = true

filter "lfs"

    smudge = git-lfs smudge --skip -- %f

remote "lqce"

    url = http://url/for/git

    review = null

    projectname = mifi/ap

    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/lqce/*

branch "mifi"

    remote = lqce

    merge = refs/heads/master

:~/retest/build/ap$ repo upload .

branch mifi ( 1 commit, Thu Jul 27 21:20:21 2017 +0800):

     3da5c7d8 build::first build

to null (y/N)? y
```